# javascript: toggle plain text to hide it like password text on click of a button

Tags: javascript, html

I do not have a `<input>` or any form. I want some way to toggle a plain text to something like `****` on click of a button.

for example I have

```
<p id='one'>google_yahoo</p>
<button id='two'>toggle</button>
```

so when I click the button once, `<p>` should become:

```
<p>************</p>
```

Then when I click the button then I should again get back `google_yahoo`

But by default I want it be in `*****` form.

What I did:

```
<script>
  function myfunction(){
  $("#two").click(function(){
  $("#one").text("abc");
  });
  };
</script>
```

Any straightforward, easy to understand solution anyone?

Comment: Put the `innerHTML` in a variable and replace the `innerHTML` with `*****`. When they click the button again, put the variable back in `innerHTML`.

Comment: It's not very complicated, you shouldn't need an expert to write it for you.

Comment: Stackoverflow.com rules said that you need to try something before ask, and share what you are trying. We are not a makemycode service

Comment: @Barmar is it possible for you to please provide code. I'm not very good in js :/

Comment: @Marco i have tried many things but its all in different context related to django...

Comment: @pyofey you should at least try once, I know it's hard if don't know js atleast try yourself from the following answers and examples then tell if any problems you are facing, and Welcome! to SO

Comment: i will take your points under consideration @Bhansa and @ Barmar. Thank you

Comment: You know you don't need a full fledged form just to use an input field, right? This can be easily achieved with a single input field and when clicking a button you just change the type from text to password.

`<input type="text">` to `<input type="password">`

Then, you use css to style the input field to look whatever you want it to look like. Simple and easier to maintain.

Comment: well, I think he has tried so we should provide some valid answer. @pyofey also edit your question to explain more about your problem and the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `text-security` css property as an option.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#two").on("click", function(){
    $("#one").toggleClass("password_field");
  })
  
})
```

```css
.password_field{
 -webkit-text-security:disc; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id='one' class="password_field">google_yahoo</p>
<button id='two'>Toggle</button>
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to create some variables to store value of your text. Try it on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nou4cs76/2/).

```
var txt = document.getElementById('one');
var btn = document.getElementById('two');
var visible = 1;
var value = '';

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  if(visible){
    value = txt.innerHTML;
    txt.innerHTML = '*'.repeat(value.length);
  }else{
    txt.innerHTML = value;
  }

  visible = !visible;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var pMemory = null;
$('button').click(function() {
  var pElement = $('p').get(0);

  if (pMemory === null) {
    // save to cache
    pMemory = $(pElement).text();
  }
  
  if (pMemory === $(pElement).text()) {
    $(pElement).text('*'.repeat(pMemory.length));
  } else {
    $(pElement).text(pMemory);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>google_yahoo</p>
<button>toggle</button>
```

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me, but how can I make it hidden by default, as this shows text on load and hides when clicked, I want to load hidden and click to reveal.